# nginfinityscroll not working

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

im using nginfinityscroll and it didnt trigger the scroll event...
my code:

```
<div class="listView" id="foundingScroll">
<label style="margin-top:10px">search:</label>  
<input ng-model="foundingFilter"/>
<div infinite-scroll="scrollSearch()" infinite-scroll-container="#foundingScroll">
<div ng-repeat="founding in foundings| myFilter:foundingFilter"><input type="checkbox" value="founding.id" ng-model="foundingsSearch[founding.name]" /><label>{{founding.name}}</label></div></div></div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: could you post your code as plunker

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot single quotes around your selector. Try this:

```
<div infinite-scroll="scrollSearch()" infinite-scroll-container="'#foundingScroll'">
```